# Unable to import QtWebEnginePage from PyQt5 on aws linux

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, pyqt5

I am working on an aws EC2 instance. I'm developing a python script to be deployed as a lambda, so I am developing on an aws linux ec2 instance (t2.micro running "Amazon Linux (Inferred)") to mimick the environment where the code will be run.

Now if I create a new virtual environment

```
$ python3 -m venv venv-name
$ source venv-name/bin/activate
$ pip3 install PyQt5
$ pip3 install PyQtWebEngine
```

So all my requirements should be installed to import pyqt. However if i run

```
$ python3
>>> from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QtWebEnginePage

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libXcomposite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm stumped, because when I google the last line of the traceback, I see a lot of people complaining about having this problem with Spyder, and with other packages. But I have no idea how to solve this for my particular case.

Comment: try use  `sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev libxcomposite-dev libxdamage-dev libxrandr-dev libxtst-dev libxss-dev libdbus-1-dev libevent-dev libfontconfig1-dev libcap-dev libpulse-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libnss3-dev libasound2-dev libegl1-mesa-dev gperf bison nodejs`

Comment: Looks like the Amazon Linux OS uses yum. Also, i'd like to zip my site-packages up into a layer to deploy with the lambda, so is there a way to install the dependencies I need with pip? Or at least make sure they get included in the layer?

Comment: then use `sudo yum install freetype-devel fontconfig-devel pciutils-devel nss-devel nspr-devel ninja-build gperf cups-devel pulseaudio-libs-devel libcap-devel alsa-lib-devel bison libXrandr-devel libXcomposite-devel libXcursor-devel libXtst-devel dbus-devel fontconfig-devel alsa-lib-devel rh-nodejs12-nodejs rh-nodejs12-nodejs-devel`

Comment: Where did you get this list from? Also, how can I ensure that these dependencies make it into my lambda layer?